# How to use Arangodb in Django database?

Tags: python, django, arangodb

I am starting developing a website, I want to use Django and Arangodb, but Django's built-in databases backend does not support arango.
django documentation refers to this in database section:

> You can use a database backend that doesn’t ship with Django by setting ENGINE to a fully-qualified path (i.e. mypackage.backends.whatever).

but I could not find anything that bridges between Django and Arango. there is this repo in GitHub https://github.com/pablotcarreira/django-arangodb but this does not support new features of Django and Arango. 
I would like any thread to lead me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Navigate this projects:

1. https://github.com/pablotcarreira/django-arangodb
2. [Build API for Django with Foxx or use ArangoDB Python driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23894545/build-api-for-django-with-foxx-or-use-arangodb-python-driver)

Comment: I checked the projects you mentioned but they don't have my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You must first create an app for the database, for example dbms, and then implement all the required items such as crud in a .py file yourself and use the query class in the view you want and return it such as list ,dict or ... .

**Note ! In the __init __ file, be sure to create an object from the created class**

Comment: You can not use the arango database as orm as far as I know like defualt database postgresq

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).